# Is there a better way to separate book title and author?

Tags: python, split, beautifulsoup

Is this the best way to split up title and author?

I need to split a book title and book author from a text chunk and put it into a list of tuples, but finding it difficult to wrap my head around it. This is an example of the text chunk:

```
The Coddling of the American Mind: How Good Intentions and Bad Ideas Are Setting Up a Generation for Failure
by Greg Lukianoff & Jonathan Haidt

The Four Agreements: A Practical Guide to Personal Freedom (A Toltec Wisdom Book)
by Don Miguel Ruiz
```

This is for a Python script using BeautifulSoup to extract the title and authors from the html.

```
result = url_connection(url_list[3]) #prints the first link for testing
x = result.find_all("h3", {"class" : "book-title"})
for a in x:
    list_of_books.append(tuple((a.text).replace('\n', '').split('by')))
```

The result I get is correct:

```
[('The Coddling of the American Mind: How Good Intentions and Bad Ideas Are Setting Up a Generation for Failure', 'Greg Lukianoff & Jonathan Haidt'), ('The Four Agreements: A Practical Guide to Personal Freedom (A Toltec Wisdom Book), 'Don Miguel Ruiz')]
```

However, if there is a `"by"` in the title then my code is screwed. What's the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: can we see the url in question?

Comment: Instead of manipulating the string after scraping it, it will be easier to get the title and author separately while scraping (you need to share the url/html so that we can help you with that). You might miss some cases while using string manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `split('by ')`, use `rsplit(' by ', 1)`.

This looks for `by` starting from the *end* of the string, and stops after one split.

I put a space before `by` just in case the author is something like `Dan Jacoby and John Doe`.

Comment: Thank you that worked like a charm. However, the space is'nt needed before the 'by' since I needed it to look for it at the beginning of a string or a newline in this case